# Normalize data to control from independent experiments, subjects and scales

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, normalization

I need to normalize the data from several subjects with different controls that have different scales. This to find the best way to present the dataset I have.

For this normalization I have tried normalizing by the avg of each control, considering transforming the data to log and percentage change based on each control. These approaches change completely the trends I see with the raw data. Since I have different subjects and controls I do not seem to figure out which way to follow.

So I would like to have some input on this

I very much appreciate your comments

Comment: It would make it easier for others to help you if you present some of the data you are working with. That said, although this is an interesting question, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Bear in mind that introducing per-subject or per-group normalization factors is essentially making assumptions about how subjects or groups are alike or not alike. My pretty strong advice is to avoid normalization as a data preprocessing step, and instead represent the normalization directly in whatever model you have.

Comment: E.g. write y = (x - a)/b + c instead of z = (x - a)/b; y = z + c, where z is your normalized variable. It is trivial in the example shown, but once you have multiple normalization factors, it becomes much harder to keep it all straight conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend try normalisation technic as [min max scaling](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/preprocessing/minmax_scaling/) or [z-score scaling](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/preprocessing/minmax_scaling/)